# Jmeter - fail an assertion when memory usage/load becomes too high or application not responding

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I am using Jmeter 2.11 to test an online application.  I'm using the Monitor Results listener to view the load and when there is no response.  It tells you how long the test was in each state, but I don't see anything that says WHEN that state occurred.  What I'd like to do is have some kind of assertion fail at the time of a 'no response' or when the load is too high.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitor Results listener displays only application server health, it doesn't check status of responses. To monitor each request status add the following test elements to your test plan:

- [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion%5C) - to check response code and whether the response contains expected value
- [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) - to check whether response is received in expected time frame
- [Size Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Size_Assertion) - to detect empty responses
- [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and [Assertion Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Assertion_Results) listeners - to know failed samplers count and associated errors.

For detailed information on using JMeter assertions see [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide.